# How to escape module pattern long namespace

Tags: javascript

why we can do this,

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = a + b;
```

but we can't this in module pattern,

```
var example = example || {};
example.UI  = {
      a : 1,
      b : 2,
      c : a + b  // this is not possible unless I use "this" or full name example.UI.a/b
};
```

Why do we must have to use "this" or "full namespace" within example.UI to get sibiling properties...

It gets really difficult to use full name sapces...

Comment: Your `c: a + b` cannot be made to work by introducing `this`, as the value of `this` has nothing to do with object initializer expressions.

Comment: For the "why" part: procedurally assigning a bunch of variables and creating an object literal are indeed two different things.

Comment: @deceze how people overcome long namespace issue with module pattern then ?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because in your second example `a` `b` and `c` are not defined! what you've actually defined is `example.UI.a` `example.UI.b` and `example.UI.c` so in a way:

```
example.UI  = {
      a : 1,
      b : 2,
      c : 3
};
```

equals

```
example.UI.a=1,
example.UI.b=2,
example.UI.c=3,
```